# How to treat javascript var

Tags: javascript, json

I have this:

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(json)
```

the output is:

```
Object {sql: "SELECT venta.cliente_tipodoc,count(*) AS cantidad FROM venta venta", results: Array[1], dataForChart: Array[1], tableOrder: Array[2], chartOrder: Array[2]…}chartOrder: Array[2]0: "cantidad"1: "cliente_tipodoc"length: 2__proto__: Array[0]dataForChart: Array[1]encabezados: Array[2]grafica: "[[agrupamiento:[[atributo:cliente_tipodoc, tabla:venta]], dato:[conteo:1, texto:Cantidad], tipo:pie-chart]]"
```

Finally what I need is to access the "grafica" values, and their inner values. I tried "json.grafica" but that gives me:

```
grafica:[[agrupamiento:[[atributo:cliente_tipodoc, tabla:venta]], dato:[conteo:1, texto:Cantidad], tipo:pie-chart]]
```

I need to access "tipo" value inside json.grafica

Thanks in advise

Comment: Your json setup within grafica is not valid you have an array but the inside is set up as if it's an object you need to change the [] to {}. Arrays which have brackets do not support key value pairs (key:value)  that is what objects use. Arrays are comma separated values in a list that can be iterated through

Comment: What is the actual content of the JSON text **before** jQuery tries to parse it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an object walker. Replace obj with your data and you can walk it to see what's inside.

```js
function walk(data, callback) {
  var chain = [];

  function loop(data) {
    if (typeof data == "object") {
      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
          chain.push("[" + i + "]");
          loop(data[i]);
          chain.pop();
        }
      } else {
        for (var k in data) {
          chain.push("." + k);
          loop(data[k]);
          chain.pop();
        }
      }
    } else {
      callback(data, chain);
    }

  }

  loop(data);
}

var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: [1, 2, 3, {
    d: 5,
    e: 6,
    f: 7
  }]
};

walk(obj, function(data, chain) {
  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += "obj" + chain.join("") + " = " + data + "\n";
});
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: It does not solve the actual issue nor does it help the OP since there is no explanation how it works.

Comment: OP needs a selector into their JSON data.  This will show the selector for every data item in a JSON object.  Originally I did console.log but it's updated to display on page.  The ".keyname" is an object key and "[number]" is an array item.